# Partial integral in Python

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I want to use the Riemann method to evaluate numerically an partial integral in Python. I would like to integrate with respect to x and find a function of t, but i don't know how do this
My fonction : `f(x) = cos(2*pi*x*t)`  its primitive between [-1/2,1/2]: `f(t) = sin(pi*t)/t`

```
def riemann(a, b, dx):
    if a > b:
        a,b = b,a
    n = int((b - a) / dx)
    s = 0.0
    x = a
    for i in range(n):
        f_i[k] = np.cos(2*np.pi*x)
        s += f_i[k]
        x += dx
    f_i = s * dx
    
    return f_i,t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing too horrible about your approach. The result does come out close to the true value:

```py
import numpy as np


def riemann(a, b, dx):
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    n = int((b - a) / dx)
    s = 0.0
    x = a
    for i in range(n):
        s += np.cos(2 * np.pi * x)
        x += dx
    return s * dx


print(riemann(0.0, 0.25, 1.0e-3))
print(1 / (2 * np.pi))
```

```
0.15965441949277526
0.15915494309189535
```

Some remarks:

- You wouldn't call this *Riemann method*. It's the [midpoint method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method) (of numerical integration).
- Pay a little more attention at the boundaries of your domain. Right now, your numerical domain is `[a - dx, b + dx]`.
- If you're looking for speed, best collect all your `x` values (perhaps with [`linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)), evaluate the function *once* with all the points, and then `np.sum` the values up. (Loops in Python are slow.)